# Jquery Menu for Mobile Navigation automatically pops out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, jquery-mobile-navbar

I have used a JQuery mobile navigation, that is used @979 wide screens. The problem I have is that when the screen is re-sized to 979px wide, the menu pops up but fully extended and covers the content of the web page. I know this is something to do with the JQuery but cannot figure it out. Here is the script:

```
$(".menu-btn").click(
function(){
$("header nav ul").slideToggle();//Slide 1st level navigation on click
    }
);

$(window).on('resize',function(){
    if($(this).width() > 979){
        $('header nav ul').removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it disappear when *more* or *less* than 979px?
Obviously, this part of code handles it:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    if($(this).width() > 979){
        $('header nav ul').removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```

When you resize the screen, this line - `$('header nav ul').removeAttr('style')` - simply drops *entire **style** attribute* of the element. Seems like the menu is hidden by having inline CSS set, i.e. `style="display: none"` and thus the menu appears when your code removes *style* attr.

Comment: You are absolutely right @AndrewDunai, it was all to do with the CSS, i just needed to change header nav ul to display:none!